# Usuário novo copiando resposta de outro site da rede

Tags: debate

Seguinte, estava vendo a lista de Analise hoje e apareceu a seguinte resposta na lista de `Primeiras publicações`: [`Resposta`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50298/14262), o usuário claramente é novo na rede SO-pt, e ele copiou a resposta do site em inglês, fez as devidas menções à resposta original, porém não acrescentou nada de novo.... "Na minha opnião", mesmo isso não sendo algo muito interessante para a rede, não é algo que vá contra as regras, porque até onde sei é permitido citar fontes da própria rede como forma de acrescentar algo a mais nas nossas respostas e perguntas.

Eu votei em deixar aberto, mas fiquei com um grande **?** na cabeça, o que fazer nesses casos? Existe de fato alguma regra quanto a isso?

Comment: Desde que seja mencionada a fonte não há problema nenhum, em principio. Podendo haver os problemas do costume de outra qualquer resposta.

Comment: Relacionada: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2321/%C3%89-correto-responder-uma-pergunta-no-sopt-com-uma-tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-uma-boa-resposta-no

Comment: Sim, mas e quando isso é a primeira resposta de um usuário, deve haver algum acompanhamento?

Comment: Não sei Marcelo. Deixa ver se os moderadores dizem alguma coisa e o que diz a comunidade.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Até onde eu sei não há nenhum problema em postar material traduzido ou mesmo trechos copiados de artigos, desde que a licença permita isso e sejam dados os devidos créditos.

Na verdade, o usuário que respondeu demonstrou até bastante esforço. Em geral os novatos postam somente um link e isso nós não queremos por aqui.

No caso de uma tradução, a grande vantagem é que pessoas que não dominam o Inglês podem ter acesso à resposta.

Por outro lado, creio que esta não deve se tornar uma regra. Uma ou outra resposta traduzida, quando apropriado, não fere o site. Mas certamente não queremos nos tornar uma versão traduzida do SOen. Se a comunidade ver que alguém está indo nessa direção, então poderemos tomar alguma atitude.

Não quero com isso desqualificar sua atenção para com o site. Devemos, sim, acompanhar esses casos de perto para que, no dia em que um problema realmente ocorrer, ele não passe despercebido.

Comment: +1 "Se a comunidade ver que alguém está indo nessa direção, então poderemos tomar alguma atitude."

Comment: Essa resposta é contraditória. Nos três primeiros parágrafos diz que "não há problema nenhum" e que a tradução é uma "vantagem", mas que se isso continuar acontecendo seria um "problema" que deve ser combatido.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy Basta não pensar de forma binária, tudo ou nada, preto ou branco.

Comment: Ou, como diria ao meu filho quando ele pergunta se pode ter sorvete no almoço: sim, pode  ter um pouco, mas não vale almoçar só sorvete.